# Git - Overiding remote branch with local branch

Tags: git

I have 2 commits on my local master branch, ahead of the remote branch.
And the remote master branch is 4 commits ahead of my local branch, 4 commits pushed by my coworker.

The 4 commits of my coworker are only causing issues, he had issues during commit & push.
Luckily my local branch is in perfect working order and he saved his work in a temp folder.

**What is the best way to get :**

A remote branch with my 2 commit pushed and the 4 commits of my coworker deleted.

In other word, I want to push my local branch to the remote and override any changes my coworker made.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, here is how.
For reference, the last commit in common between the remote master and my local master will be named **A**.

**First reset the local commits and stash them :**

```
git reset --mixed A
git add .
git stash
```

**Then pull the remote master :**
This causes no merge conflict as the local branch is now only behind the remote master.

```
git pull
```

**Revert the 4 unwanted commits :**
Multiples methods available, I used checkout to commit **A**.

```
git checkout -f A -- .
```

**Commit & push to remote :**

```
git commit -m "Revert to commit 'A'"
git push
```

**Restore local commits stashed before the operation :**

```
git stash apply
git add .
git commit -m "Local commits"
git push
```

Feel free to edit to improve this method.